# Accessing member variables from aggregated class

Tags: c++, aggregation

Just trying to get `stack.cpp`'s push function to increment `max_size_` variable by 1.

Array.h:

```
template <typename T>
class Array: public BaseArray<T>
{
public:

//loads of fun code
private:
  size_t max_size_;
};
```

Stack.cpp:

```
//...even more fun code...
template <typename T>
void Stack <T>::push (T element)
{
    ArrayStack::max_size_++;

}
```

Stack.h:

```
template <typename T>
class Stack
{
public:

  Stack (void);

private:
    Array <T> ArrayStack; 
};
```

Error:

```
 error: ‘ArrayStack’ is not a class or namespace
  ArrayStack::max_size_++;
```

Or if I run it with just `max_size_`:

```
template <typename T>
void Stack <T>::push (T element)
{

    max_size_++;
}

error: ‘max_size_’ was not declared in this scope
  max_size_++;
```

Comment: Recommended read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: You really ought to get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: The `::` is the scope operator, not the member select operator, which is `.`. You *have* seen a syntax similar to e.g. `ArrayStack.max_size` before? However that's not your only problem, because the member variable you try to access is *private*. If you add an element to the `Array` shouldn't the size be updated automatically the `Array` class itself?

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't do that without changing something.
`max_size_++;` is a private member of `ArrayStack`, so you cannot change it from inside a `Stack` method.

**Option 1 (better):** Add a method to your `ArrayStack` that increments the value by one `void incMaxSize() { max_size_++; }` and call it instead

**Option 2 (worse):** Make the `Stack` class a friend of `ArrayStack`

**Option 3 (even worse):** Make the `max_size_` variable public and then change the call to `ArrayStack.max_size_++;`

Answer (score 0):

Since you made max_size_ private in your Array class you'll need to create a getter and setter to access it outside of that class. Then in your Stack class you can get the max_size_ value and save it in a local variable and then set it to 1 + it's current value to achieve max_size_++